# OraOLEDB.Oracle provider returning the wrong results

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oraoledb

Here's a bizarre one for you. I'm running a simple query against a table that looks like this:

```
select expiration_date from Tbl where expiration_date > sysdate - 1
```

In SQL Developer, this is returning 35 rows. A VB.NET application, calling the exact same SQL statement, using the `OraOLEDB.Oracle` provider only returns 30 rows.

Here's my connection string (broken up for legibility):

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)
(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)));
User Id=rps;
Password=*******;
OLEDB.NET=True;
```

And here's sample code (we're in the `ProcessRequest` section of a generic ASHX handler):

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
conn.Open()
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
Dim sql As String = "select expiration_date from Tbl where expiration_date > sysdate - 1"
cmd.CommandText = sql
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
context.Response.Write("RESULTS: " & vbCrLf)
Dim i As Int32 = 1
While reader.Read()
    context.Response.Write(i.ToString() & ". " & reader.GetValue(0).ToString() & vbCrLf)
    i = i + 1
End While

reader.Close()
cmd.Dispose()
conn.Close()
conn.Dispose()
```

If I change the query to say `... where expiration_date < sysdate + 15`  it works fine.

What on earth is going on? This is ODAC 11.2.0.3 if it helps.

---

**Update 1:** I removed ODAC 11.2.0.3 and upgraded to ODAC 12.1.0.1 (ORAOLEDB12.DLL). Behavior unchanged.

---

**Update 2:** Well this is interesting. I switched to ODP.NET just to see what would happen. Guess what? SAME EXACT RESULTS. I cannot even blame the provider anymore. I need a drink.

---

**Update 3:** Finally had the bright idea to see what dates were being excluded. There are five expiration_dates that occur in the month of November after today that should be included in the results. Those are precisely the ones that are excluded. So sysdate-1 is not doing what you'd expect when called from C#. Time for another drink.

Comment: Does the same happens if you use `trunc()` on the dates? Also can you try populating a DataTable via DataAdapter.Fill and see how many rows are returned?

Comment: No difference with TRUNC(). The field is a DATE datatype. The original code used a DataAdapter; I switched to a DataReader to try to figure out what was going on. This is maintenance work on an older application that was built using MSDAORA (Microsoft's OLEDB provider for Oracle) which is being deployed to a 64-bit server and I don't think it's an option to go back.

Comment: Weird. Any chance to try it with Oracle own OLEDB provider? They have 64bit versions

Comment: This is their OLEDB provider, from the 64-bit ODAC collection. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html Release 4 ... maybe I should try release 5, or see if I can use v12 with my 11g database...?

Comment: Oracle [`sysdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions179.htm#SQLRF06124) function returns current time, not only date. So you need to use [`trunc(sysdate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151) if you want to work with day boundaries. Without it with `sysdate - 1` you get a moment 24 hours before moment of execution of query.

Comment: I tried trunc and saw no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. Oracle SQL Developer runs everything in a transaction, and I wasn't `COMMIT`ting anything. I hang my head in shame and can only hope this will serve as a warning to others.